# How to Download the file in the /data/data/[Application Package name folder]/files in android using react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

While I am trying to download the file. It is not storing in the path **/data/data/[Application Package name folder]/files** but it is downloading in **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[Application Package name folder]/files**.

I have tried using the **rn-fetch-blob** package as well as the **react-native-blob-util** package. I am getting the error as an unsupported path. for reference, I am attaching the error screenshot

[image]

**Below is the code I have written for download**

```js
const downloadRecord = async () => {
  let FILE_URL = `https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf`;

  let file_ext = getFileExtention(FILE_URL);
  file_ext = "." + file_ext[0];
  let extension = file_ext;
  let date = new Date();
  let Name = bookID; // + Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2);

  try {
    const { config, fs } = ReactNativeBlobUtil;
    const DownloadDir =
      Platform.OS == "ios"
        ? `${fs.dirs.LibraryDir}/name/`
        : `${fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/name/`;
    let fileName = Name + extension;
    let pdfPath = DownloadDir + fileName;
    console.log("Path", pdfPath);
    let options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        //Related to the Android only
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        path: pdfPath,
        description: "downloading...",
      },
      path: pdfPath,
    };

    //console.log(FILE_URL)
    config(options)
      .fetch("GET", FILE_URL)
      .progress((received, total) => {
        console.log("progress method", (received / total) * 100);
      })
      .then((res) => {
        //console.log('res -> ', JSON.stringify(res));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Toast.show("Error downloading Training Record.");
      });
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't have access to the `/data/data/...`. It isn't a lack of ability for the existing libraries. The `/data` path is a system path and it needs *root* access to open/read it or modify it.

I don't know what is your need that you made this solution to store the files there, but the `FileSystem.DocumentDirectoryPath` is a cross-platform and good directory to use for downloading files.

And the `FileSystem` is:

```js
import FileSystem from 'react-native-fs';
```

Comment: I Want to download a file and store in the /data/data folder so it is used for application purpose. Even using file system it is getting unsupported Path error.

Comment: @MURTHYKSN, Have you read my answer?